# How do I get a list of all installed packages in debian or ubuntu

Tags: apt-get, dpkg

I recently destroyed the system partition on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.  I hadn't bothered to back it up since I knew I could easily restore it from a DVD.  The problem is that every once in a while I come across a package that I need that I don't have.  Of course, I can install it easily with apt-get, but that interrupts my work flow.

It's too late for this machine, of course, but in the future, I would like to have a list of all the packages installed on the machine.  Then I could do something clever like

```
xargs < file_with_list_of_pckgs | apt-get install
```

Then periodically, I can create a list of packages.  If I ever zap the system partition again, I can install Ubuntu from DVD and then use apt-get to get the packages I am missing.

I also have to backup everything under /etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-liner which will generate such a list on a single line.

```
dpkg -l | awk  '{print $2}' > package_list.txt
```

The package_list.txt file may have a few weird lines at the top, which are easy to get rid of using your favorite text editor.  You can then install all of the modules you need with

```
xargs < package_list.txt apt-get install -y
```

Unfortunately, you need the -y switch because xargs redirects stdin, so you are going to install all of the packages in the package_list.txt that are out of date.  However, you probably want to do that anyway or else you wouldn't try this stunt.